# Configuring the display properties on openSuse (Gnome) running as VirtualBox VM

Tags: linux, opensuse, virtual-machine, display-settings

I just created a VM using Suse Studio and I built just a simple openSUSE 11.3 VM based on the gnome template. I have not added any other software (except for Firefox and the Kernel modules, to be able to add VirtualBox Guest Additions, but using Yast).

I am trying to use the gnome display program to change my resolution, and I am getting the following message: "Display configuration could not be run" - "Failed to execute child process "gnome-display-properties" (No such file or directory)".

Of course I tried to lookup gnome-display in the software repository, but I had no luck there. Anyone has run into the same issue?

Comment: Once I installed the gnome-control-center through the "Install/Remove Software" option in the "System" menu, I can now change my screen resolution.  Thank You!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is whether or not you actually have the necessary files installed on your VM. gnome-display-properties seems to belong to the gnome-control-center package for OpenSuse. You can open the Install Software program in OpenSuse and look to see if this package is installed, or you can do a search using `zypper search gnome-control-center`. You will need to be the super user to install it, if it is not already installed.